# Does cancelling the deletion of a folder restore files in the folder that were deleted?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-recovery, recycle-bin

I accidentally clicked delete on a folder full of personal photos. Before I was able to hit cancel, the message below the progress bar was showing that some files had already been deleted. The recycle bin is empty. Did the files that were deleted before I hit cancel get resurrected, or are they gone for good?

Comment: Are you missing files? I suspect so, Windows will delete each file individually then the empty folder. If they were on the Windows drive, they should be in recycle bin, but if it's an external drive they are gone. But on better a note, a simple undelete tool should be able to restore them if done soon so the disk space isn't reallocated to other files

Comment: External drives have a recycle bin, only flash drives delete permanently.

Comment: Deletions that have occurred will not be restored automatically. you will have to restore those files from another source, like the recyclebin, or backup. Otherwise you can try data recovery tools like like recuva or easus or photorec to undelete the files, though you may lose metadata like the file name.

Answer (score 3):

They are likely deleted, but not necessarily for good.

Assuming you haven't used the drive since (if you have, chances of recovery are significantly reduced but still not impossible), you may be able to use software such as [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) to attempt to recover the files. This can take a variable amount of time and have varied success, but you should be able to run a data recovery utility over the drive and hopefully retrieve any items that have been removed.

Answer (score 2):

[Jonno's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1051867/719701) is better than mine, but in case anyone else is wondering, if you cancel it while it's still "Preparing to delete", then it did not delete anything. (However, that conclusion is just based on one attempt, so it's not a guarantee.)

<sub>(I realize this is answering a slightly different question, so if you recommend that I move it to a separate question, please let me know instead of downvoting. :-) )</sub>

Comment: You haven't posted an answer, so the comparison to Jonno's isn't clear.  The rest is really more of a comment than an answer to what was asked.

Comment: @fixer1234 True. I understand that there's a need to prevent spam, but it's too bad that I can't (a) upvote Jonno's answer to make it appear above mine, and/or (b) post my "answer" as a comment. (I don't have enough reputation.)